# A problem about Subsets, symmetric differences and set cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Problem: For an non-empty set $S$, select half of its subsets (call this collection of subsets $C$), so that any symmetric difference of two selected sub-sets are not among the ones selected.

Prove that $S$ has an non-empty subset $A$, such that $|A \cap B|$ is odd, for all $B$ in collection of selected collection of subsets $C$.

My Thoughts:

"Any symmetric difference of two selected sub-sets are not among the ones selected" is an interesting condition, and given that we have to select half of possible subsets, this should eliminate a lot of the possibilities already, but not able to make much progress beyond that.

Comment: is set S arbitrary? in case the cardinal of  the power set of S is infinite or odd, how do you selct " half" of its subsets?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Half the subsets, not half the elements. A set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: Take any $a\in S$. Select all subsets containing $a$.

Comment: @almagest yes that's an interesting example, but I think the problem means "for any such selection of a collection, there exists a subset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $S$ is a finite set with $n$ elements.
Let $C':=\mathcal P(S) \setminus C$.

First, fix an arbitrary $X\in C$. Then the set $X\triangle C:=\{X\triangle Y:Y\in C\}$ has the same cardinality as $C$ and consists only of sets of $C'$, so by the hypothesis, $X\triangle C=C'$.

Consequently, $C'$ *is* closed under symmetric difference, as for $Y,Z\in C$, we have $(X\triangle Y)\triangle(X\triangle Z)=Y\triangle Z\, \in C'$.

Now, looking at it through the correspondence $\mathcal P(S)\longleftrightarrow {\Bbb F_2}^n\, =:V$, where $\Bbb F_2$ is the 2-element field, $\triangle$ translates to $+$, and the above conclusion means that $C'$ is a linear *hyperplane* of $V$, and $C$ is its (only) affine coset.

Let $A$ correspond to the 'normal vector' of this hyperplane $C'$, i.e. it satisfies $\langle A,X\rangle=0$ if $X\in C'$ and $1$ if $X\in C$, where $\langle A,X\rangle=\sum_i A_iX_i$ using operations in $\Bbb F_2$, i.e. modulo $2$.

Comment: I might be missing some basics.. do you mind to elaborate "the above conclusion means that C′ is a linear hyperplane of V, and C is its (only) affine coset."?

Comment: $C'$ is closed under addition over $\Bbb F_2$ (=symmetric difference), and we have only 2 scalars: $0$ and $1$, so it's a subspace. As $|C'|=2^{n-1}$, its dimension is $n-1$. Two such cosets fit in $V$: the linear space which contains the zero, and its set complement.

Comment: @Berci does your conclusion mean that any subset of $S$ is either in C or in C'. Also does this then mean that any subset is either in C or can be written as the symmetric difference of two elements of C ? I think this is what C' means.